# Taking a stack and printing it in reverse order in UART

Tags: assembly, printing, stack, bit

So basically I have a class where the teachers designed the program that we use, and they basically said "Do these labs with no background information".

Right now I have to make a RPN calculator using assembly and I have gotten all of it coded except i have to print it in reverse order (the stack).

It would be easy, except we are using 2 digit numbers in each stack slot.

My simple question is how can I take a 2 digit number and split it into each bit.

An example would be having the number 52 and splitting the bits into 5 (then sends through 5 in UART) and 2 (then sends 2 through UART) so the output would be 52.

Comment: Also, in this nice little program, there is no division operator. Only add, subtract, and multiply.

Answer (score 1):

To get the digits of a number, divide by the base (in this case base 10 I assume). The remainder is the least significant digit; the quotient is the remaining digits. Repeat for more digits.

With no divide instruction, and only two digits, here's a cheesy approach:

```
quotient = 0;

while (number >= 10)
{
    number = number - 10;
    quotient = quotient + 1;
}
print msdigit;
print number;
```

Make sure `number` is positive first!

Comment: That would work if we had a divide function. I created my own division type function in the program but I am not sure if it works, Will test.

Comment: Awesome. Will try this. have to finish my phys 2 HW then get this done before 330.